# Passing row value from input to ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table with multiple rows with different values - values are inside hidden input - Just like this:

```
<tr> 
   <td>UserName 1 <input type="hidden" class="EmployeeID" name="EmployeeID[]" value="1" />
   <td><input type="button" class="btn btnDelEmployee" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
   <td>UserName 12 <input type="hidden" class="EmployeeID" name="EmployeeID[]" value="2" />
   <td><input type="button" class="btn btnDelEmployee" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to pass the value of the row once I click the delete input.
I tried this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnDelEmployee', function () {
      $.post('', {DelEmployee:1, EmployeeID: $(".EmployeeID").val()}, function(data){

      },'json');                    
 });
```

When I click the second row I get the value of the first row, instead of getting the value of the second row.

Comment: where is the html for `#btnAddClose`?

Comment: @Omi fixed it to `.btnDelEmployee` .. it was a mistake by from my side .. but not fixing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand you to add an attribute to your field like :

```
<input type="button" class="btn btnDelEmployee" value="Delete" data-id="2" />
```

Then :

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnAddClose', function () {
      $.post('', {btnAddClose:1, EmployeeID: $(this).attr('data-id')}, function(data){

      },'json');                    
 });
```

Comment: I was able to use `$(this).data('id')`  too